# Resolving nested/heirarchial item references with SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, nested, hierarchy

I need to setup a database that will track an inventory of items (parts, components, etc) contained inside other items (boxes, enclosures, etc).

I'm new to database design/usage, but I'm familiar with the basics and how to Google, however I'm currently stuck on how to actually track items contained inside other items at the database level.

In short, if a query returns either

1. an item contained by another item (such as a component inside an enclosure)
2. an item (such as an enclosure) that contains other items

then I want to include the containing item, or the contained item, along with the original item, in the query results.

To resolve #1 above, I figure I can include a `container_id` field in my DB schema that references the ID of the containing item, then write a fancy SELECT query that appropriately consults any `container_id` values it finds and automatically includes those results. I have no idea how to do this though.

I'm completely stuck on how to resolve problem #2. If an item I'm searching for (such as a box) contains multiple child items (the contents of the box), I want to include the box, and its contents (ie, all of the child items), in the results. I have no idea how to represent this relationship in terms of SQL queries or DB design.

Furthermore, if I have 5 of a given item (say, a sound card), 1 might exist in a computer case, 2 might exist in a box inside a container in the corner, and 2 more might be in this quick-grab tray on my desk. I need to be able to recognize all of this at the DB level and track it.

I'm asking here because I simply have no idea what to Google as I'm on completely unfamiliar territory in this situation.

For what it's worth, the database will probably only contain about 4000 or so items as a reasonable (read: decently padded) upper limit - so while it would certainly be both inelegant and inefficient to simply query through the database multiple times, it wouldn't be the absolute end of the world if I was able to find a query technique that didn't skyrocket too exponentially.

Also, for reference, this is not a homework challenge (although it sure does feel like one) - I need to clean up my garage *big-time*, and there are so many tiny bits and pieces it's gotten to the point where I critically need to build an inventory system to keep track of everything.

Comment: Please show your create table statements (or at least the relevant part of it). Also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I put together some experimental table designs a few days ago but my architectural spec has changed since then so I'm starting again. Thus I don't actually have any code as yet, although this is perhaps advantageous as it means I can most easily implement the most effective solution.

Comment: To clarify, I'm asking this question since it's the most difficult part of the table design - once I know where I'm going with this I should be able to get started. EDIT: Context is "need to fix the garage and do it PROPERLY" - not a schoolwork assignment =P

Comment: How many nesting levels can there be?

Comment: For reference, I just significantly edited my question to rephrase it and include information I originally completely forgot. However, the changes do not invalidate the comments up to now.